# Testing if an object has been deallocated

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a situation where occasionally my `-tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:` method asks for the count of a deallocated NSArray. I'd like to be able to test for this array being deallocated in a way that's safe and doesn't make a call to a zombie.

My code currently looks like:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (! self.offers){
        return 0;
    }
    return [self.offers count];
}
```

I just debugger-stepped through this and observed it passing the `! self.offers` test and then crashing brutally on `[self.offers count]`. I have NSZombies turned on, and at that line I get the NSLog message:

```
-[__NSArrayM count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x283dc0
```

So whatever self.offers is, at this point, is not nil, but is also not pointed at anything valid. How do I test for that?

EDIT: Thanks for the tough-love, friends. I've figured out why I've been having trouble with my memory management--it's actually been an issue of delegate relationships lingering longer than they were useful. See here for the full answer to my problem: 
[Managing calls to objects that get deallocated when the view is backed out of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095995/managing-calls-to-objects-that-get-deallocated-when-the-view-is-backed-out-of)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if I have a pointer to released object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280799/how-to-determine-if-i-have-a-pointer-to-released-object)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not possible to "test" for this-- once an object is deallocated, it's gone, and the pointer to it is effectively garbage. Doing anything with it is liable to crash.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but the only way to get this to work right is to make sure the memory management around (in this case) `offers` is correct at all uses-- retain and release correctly at all the points where that instance variable is manipulated, and it will never be non-nil garbage.

You should try running the static analyzer (Build->Build and Analyze) to start with-- this tool can help flag memory management pattern issues without a lot of extra digging on your part.

Comment: +1 and set `offers` to `nil` once you've relinquished ownership of it.  That way you can change your code to `return [self.offers count];`, since `[nil count]` returns 0.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid the problem by fixing the code so it does not deallocate the array when you obviously still need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
-(void)dealloc { ... }
```

And leave it empty if it's the right to do, and add breakpoint in it.

This answer correct to `ARC` and `NON-ARC`

Comment: `dealloc` cannot be empty in non-arc. You *must* have `[super dealloc]` as the last line of this method.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be relevant to your question (testing if it is deallocated) - but it seems like your *offers* array has the same or longer lifetime than your `UITableViewController`, are you certain you are retaining this array or that you aren't accidentally releasing it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with what quixoto has said above.

Another thing you have to ask yourself is, is my application designed correctly? A tableview relies on a datasource to populate it (which in your case is the `offers` array), so if you're deallocating it somewhere in the code then you need to step back and rethink your design.

If you're testing for whether it's deallocated because you're trying to 'fix' it from a previous problem, then it might be worth looking into your code to see where it is being retained/released.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once an object is deallocated, it's gone, and the pointer to it is effectively garbage. Doing anything with it is liable to crash.

However it is POSSIBLE to test. There is a workaround for it. (Although workarounds are not a substitute for good design practices!):
You have a global BOOL variable, which you set on the alloc. Here's an example of use for checking whether a AVAudioPlayer isPlaying. If it was playing, and the view was closed, the app would crash. Simply stopping the music was not an option due to background threads, etc. But calling [newPlayer isPlaying] crashes when newPlayer is already released! So a BOOL flag workaround made it work. (Any good design practice comments on this would be valuable.)

```
// In implementation
static AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer;
static BOOL hasMusicFinishedPlaying;

// When Playing the music, set flag
    newPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath] error:nil];    
    hasMusicFinishedPlaying = NO;

// Callback method to release new player in playKeySound
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)newPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag {

    [newPlayer release];
    hasMusicFinishedPlaying = YES;
}

// On going back to another page. We don't want to keep ViewController in stack.

    if (!hasMusicFinishedPlaying){
        return;
    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```